# iPad startup orientation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

In my info plist, I have defined Supported interface orientations (iPad) as all orientations, and it works. The only problem is if I start in landscape mode, it starts as portrait, but If I rotate and then rotate back, it fixes.
So how can I make it so it adopts to the startup orientation?
thANKS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the orientation you need by implementing the following in either your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or in a view controller's `viewWillAppear:`.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

The UIViewController that is installed as the root controller via `[window addSubview:viewController.view];` should implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` function and return YES to all supported orientations.

The iPad starts the views with Portrait orientation and then rotates all the views by calling `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` function with a duration of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the order of the interface orientations from the main .plist files is important also. E.g http://monosnap.com/image/jJeImyVp6G3Mq1uXLSAVRA0te2VwgJ Means that at startup the app will be in landscape, with the home button on the right.